# Novice implementation of TicTacToe in Haskell

Tags: beginner, haskell, tic-tac-toe

I want to learn Haskell and figured the best way to do it is to write a simple TicTacToe implementation. However the result feels very inelegant and I think it might be the best playground for your rants and give me an opportunity to learn some lessons.

```
{-|
TODO: -filter symmetric states from game tree
|-}

module Tictactoe  where

import Data.List

initialBoardStr = "         "    

data Tree a = Node a [Tree a]  deriving (Show)

type Board = String
type Points = Int
type Pos = Int

expandGameTree :: Board -> Tree Board
expandGameTree state = Node state $ succesors state
        where succesors cur_state = [Node s (succesors s) 
                | s <- indicateAllowedMoves cur_state, s /= []]

evalBoard :: Board -> Points
evalBoard board
        | win && nextSymb board == "X" = 100
        | win && nextSymb board == "O" = (-100)
        | otherwise = 0
        where win = winingBoard board

evalState :: Tree Board -> Points
evalState (Node a []) = evalBoard a
evalState (Node a (x:xs)) = (minimax a) [evalState b | b <- (x:xs)]

minimax board
    | nextSymb board == "X" = minimum
    | nextSymb board == "O" = maximum

nextMove = (makeNextMove . expandGameTree)

numerate :: Board -> Board
numerate board
    | length (findIndices (==' ') board) == 0 = board
    | otherwise = numerate $ replace board (idx board) (show (idx board)) 
        where idx board = (findIndices (==' ') board) !! 0

makeNextMove (Node a (x:xs)) = getBoardFromTree ((x:xs) !! (maxIndex (rates (x:xs))))
    where maxIndex xs = head $ filter ((== maximum xs) . (xs !!)) [0..]
          rates (x:xs) = [evalState c | c <- (x:xs)]

getBoardFromTree (Node a (x:xs)) = a
getBoardFromTree (Node a []) = a

showBoard :: Board -> String
showBoard board =  "|" ++ (row 0) ++ "|\n|" ++ (row 1) ++ "|\n|" ++ (row 2) ++ "|\n"
           where numeratedBoard = numerate board
                 row i = takeRange numeratedBoard [3*i..(3*i)+2]

indicateAllowedMoves :: Board -> [Board]
indicateAllowedMoves board
        | winingBoard board = [] 
        | otherwise = [replace board i symb | i <- [0..8], board !! i == ' '] 
        where symb = nextSymb board

replace :: String -> Pos -> String -> String
replace str idx char = take idx str ++ char ++ drop (idx+1) str

isAllowedMove :: Board -> Pos -> Bool 
isAllowedMove board pos = elem next allowed
        where next = insertInBoardStr board pos
              allowed = indicateAllowedMoves board

winingRow :: String -> Bool
winingRow row 
    | row == "XXX" || row == "OOO" = True
    | otherwise = False

rows :: Board -> [String]
rows board = row ++ cols ++ diag
    where row = [takeRange board [i..(i+2)] | i <- [0,3,6]]
          cols = [takeRange board $ map (+i) [0,3,6] | i <- [0..2]]
          diag = [takeRange board [0,4,8]] ++ [takeRange board [2,4,6]]

winingBoard :: Board -> Bool
winingBoard board = any winingRow $ rows board

--takeRange :: String -> [Int] -> String
takeRange str range = [str !! i | i <- range]

insertInBoardStr :: Board -> Pos -> Board
insertInBoardStr board pos = replace board pos symb
        where symb = nextSymb board

nextSymb :: Board -> String
nextSymb board 
    | countLetters board 'X' ==  countLetters board 'O' = "X"
    | otherwise = "O"
    where countLetters str c = length $ filter (== c) str

curSymb :: Board -> String
curSymb board
    | nextSymb board == "X" = "O"
    | otherwise = "X"


isEquivivalent :: String -> String -> Bool
isEquivivalent row1 row2
        | row1 == row2 = True
        | row1 == reverse row2 = True
        | otherwise = False

play board = do
    putStr "\ESC[2J"
    putStrLn $ showBoard board
    if (winingBoard board) == True then
        putStrLn ("Player: " ++  (curSymb board) ++ " wins")
     else
        putStrLn "Make your move: "
    input <- getLine
    let pos = (read input :: Int)
    if (isAllowedMove board pos) == True then
        play (nextMove (insertInBoardStr board pos))
     else
        play board

main = play initialBoardStr
```

Comment: a different implementation of the same "problem": http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68345/tictactoe-in-haskell

Comment: @Vogel612 The question which you linked to is mine, and I implemented a Tic Tac Toe game. On the other hand, OP implemented a Tic Tac Toe AI. Both are related but isn't really the same.

Comment: @wei2912 ohh carp.. I don't speak haskell... but the title and text didn't make it apparent your and his "problem" are different :( That's why I prefer to add a "What does my code do?" to questions I ask ;) Thank you for clarifying