# m,n,k-game (i.e. generalized tic-tac-toe)

Tags: beginner, game, haskell, tic-tac-toe

I'm back after [Tic-Tac-Toe in Haskell](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/68345/tictactoe-in-haskell) with a new version.

I added Haddock documentation and wrote a generalized version known as the [m,n,k-game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M,n,k-game). By doing so, I had to redefine `Game` and `getSeqs`. `getSeqs` as of now contains two annoyingly-long list comprehensions which I'd like to get rid of.

I tried to integrate `gameState` into `Game` so that the client won't need to check the game state all the time. However, this makes `move` rather messy.

Also, I wrote a test client for it (under the `main` function). I wrote the `startGame` function which seems extremely long. Is there a way to simplify it?

I'd appreciate any other comments on this code.

```
{-|
  m,n,k-game implementation in Haskell.
  Two players take turns in placing a stone of their color on an m×n board,
  the winner being the player who first gets k stones of their own color in a
  row, horizontally, vertically, or diagonally.

  For example, tic-tac-toe is a 3,3,3-game and gomuku is a 19,19,5-game.
-}

module MNKGame (
    newGame,
    move,
    moves
) where

import Control.Lens (set, ix)
import Data.List (tails, transpose)
import Data.Maybe (catMaybes)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

data Player = X | O
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

type Marking = Maybe Player
newtype Grid = Grid [[Marking]]

instance Show Grid where
    show (Grid grid) = (unlines . map showRow) grid
        where showRow = unwords . map showMarking
              showMarking (Nothing) = "_"
              showMarking (Just a) = show a

data GameState = Won Player | Draw | Running
    deriving (Show, Read, Eq)

data Game = Game {
    grid :: Grid,
    m :: Int,
    n :: Int,
    k :: Int,
    curTurn :: Player,
    gameState :: GameState
} deriving Show


-- Basic Definitions

nextPlayer :: Player -> Player
nextPlayer X = O
nextPlayer O = X

emptyGrid :: Int -- ^ number of rows
          -> Int -- ^ number of cols
          -> Grid
emptyGrid m n = Grid $ replicate m $ replicate n Nothing

chop :: Int -> [a] -> [[a]]
chop k xs = [take k ys | ys <- zipWith const (tails xs) (drop (k - 1) xs)]

-- |The 'getSeqs' function returns a list of sequences.
-- A sequence is a row, column or diagonal.
-- This utility function returns all sequences.
getSeqs :: Grid
        -> Int -- ^ number of rows
        -> Int -- ^ number of cols
        -> Int -- ^ number of marks in a row to win
        -> [[Marking]] -- ^ list of sequences
getSeqs (Grid marks) m n k =
    rows ++ cols ++ fDiags ++ bDiags
    where
        rows = concatMap (chop k) marks
        cols = concatMap (chop k) $ transpose marks
        fDiags = [[marks !! p !! q | (p, q) <- zip [i .. i + k - 1] [j .. j + k - 1]] | i <- [0 .. m - k], j <- [0 .. n - k]]
        bDiags = [[marks !! p !! q | (p, q) <- zip [i, i - 1 .. i - k] [j .. j + k - 1]] | i <- [k - 1 .. m - 1], j <- [0 .. n - k]]

-- |Returns the current game state of a game.
getGameState :: Grid
             -> Int -- ^ number of rows
             -> Int -- ^ number of cols
             -> Int -- ^ number of marks in a row to win
             -> GameState
getGameState grid@(Grid marks) m n k
    | isWin X = Won X
    | isWin O = Won O
    | isDraw = Draw
    | otherwise = Running
    where
        isWin player = any (all (== Just player)) $ getSeqs grid m n k
        isDraw = all (notElem Nothing) marks

-- |Creates a new m,n,k-game.
newGame :: Int -- ^ number of rows
        -> Int -- ^ number of cols
        -> Int -- ^ number of marks in a row to win
        -> Game -- ^ Game data type
newGame m n k = Game {
    grid = emptyGrid m n,
    m = m,
    n = n,
    k = k,
    curTurn = X,
    gameState = Running
}

-- |The `move` function makes a move given the row and column index.
-- It returns 'Nothing' if the move is invalid.
-- Otherwise, it returns the new game.
move :: Int -- ^ row index
     -> Int -- ^ column index
     -> Game
     -> Maybe Game
move i j (Game (Grid grid) m n k player gameState)
    | gameState == Draw = Nothing
    | gameState == Won X || gameState == Won O = Nothing
    | validCoord i j = case grid !! i !! j of
        Just _ -> Nothing
        Nothing -> let newGrid = Grid $ set (ix i . ix j) (Just player) grid in
            Just Game {
                grid = newGrid,
                m = m,
                n = n,
                k = k,
                curTurn = nextPlayer player,
                gameState = getGameState newGrid m n k
            }
    | otherwise = Nothing
    where validCoord i j = i >= 0 && j >= 0 && i < m && j < n

-- |Returns all possible moves from a game.
moves :: Game -> [Game]
moves game@(Game _ m n _ _ _) = catMaybes [move x y game | x <- [0 .. m - 1], y <- [0 .. n - 1]]

-- Testing Client

-- |This client is a 2-player version of Tic-Tac-Toe.
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Make a move by typing (i, j). i represents the row and j represents the column."
    let game = newGame 3 3 3
    putStrLn $ show $ grid game
    startGame game

startGame :: Game -> IO ()
startGame game = do
    line <- getLine
    case readMaybe line :: Maybe (Int, Int) of
        Just (i, j) -> case move i j game of
            Just newGame -> do
                putStrLn $ show $ grid newGame
                case gameState newGame of
                    Won a -> putStrLn $ "Player " ++ show a ++ " won!"
                    Draw -> putStrLn "It's a draw!"
                    Running -> startGame newGame
            Nothing -> do
                putStrLn "Invalid move. Please input a valid move."
                startGame game
        Nothing -> do
            putStrLn "Invalid move. Please input a valid move."
            startGame game
```

Comment: Ah, generalization to MNK style! Now we're talking. You might want to implement [Ultimate Tic-Tac-Toe](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1471/weekend-challenge-reboot/1472#1472) next.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg That looks interesting, but I think I'll stop here. I have a couple of other plans which I need to start on. :)

Comment: Not worth a seperate answer I guess, but you can simplify `putStrLn $ show` by just replacing it with `print`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty slick.

You might want to add definitions and exports for `tictactoe = newgame 3 3 3` and `gomuku = newgame 19 19 5` for convenience.

The parentheses around `Nothing` in the local definition of `showMarking` for the `Show Grid` instance are unnecessary. You could also implement or replace `showMarking` with `maybe "_" show`. Why pattern match when you've got a handy higher order function?

Definitely add a comment to explain `chop`, it took me a moment to realize what it's doing (it's certainly very clever!).

Cleaning up `getSeqs` is a *very* interesting problem. The easiest portion is realizing that the back diagonals can be found by the same exact process as the forward diagonals if you just transform your matrix with `map reverse`. The next key step is realizing that if we can generate the full length (as opposed to k-length) diagonals, we can use `chop` again.

```
-- Find the main diagonal (↘) of a matrix
diagonal :: [[a]] -> [a]
diagonal []           = []
diagonal ((x:_):rows) = x : diagonal (map tail rows) -- _0,0 : ↘ (m-1 × n-1)

-- Find all ↘ diagonals of a matrix
diagonals :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
diagonals m =       map diagonal (init . tails $          m)  -- (i=m  ,1) ↘ (i×n)
           ++ tail (map diagonal (init . tails $ tranpose m)) -- (j=n-1,1) ↘ (m×j)

-- Thus (code fragment):
fdiag = concatMap (chop k) $ diagonals marks
bdiag = concatMap (chop k) $ diagonals (map reverse marks)
```

Don't use guards where pattern matching will do.

```
move i j (Game (Grid grid) m n k player Running)
    | validCoord i j = -- ...
    | otherwise      = Nothing
move _ _ _           = Nothing
```

I'm not sure that there are appreciable improvements left to make to `move`. You could use `RecordWildCards` and `NamedFieldPuns`, maybe record update notation, but I don't find it that bad to begin with.

Use even more `do`-notation in `startGame` to unify the `Maybe` handling, and extract the commonalities.

```
startGame :: Game -> IO ()
startGame game = do
    line <- getLine
    maybe retry next $ do
        (i, j) <- readMaybe line
        move i j game
  where
    retry = putStrLn "Invalid move. Please input a valid move." >> startGame game
    next newGame = do
        putStrLn $ show $ grid newGame
        case gameState newGame of
            Won a   -> putStrLn $ "Player " ++ show a ++ " won!"
            Draw    -> putStrLn   "It's a draw!"
            Running -> startGame newgame
```